# My stow and go 2nd row seats will not fold down into the storage area? I have a 2010 dodge grand caravan

Tags: chevrolet

we have a swivel and go 2010 dodge grandcaravan.  The 2nd row seating seats will not fold down into the storage compartment.  Can you tell me if and how they do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What does the owners manual say?